# Converting unformatted string timestamp value to Unix_Timestamp in Impala

Tags: sql, timestamp, unix-timestamp, impala

I have a string timestamp column as below in one of the table.

```
Column  
20210108003444  ---- 8th Jan 2021 00.34 AM  
20201109013716      
2020112422811
```

How can I convert this into a unix_timestamp in Impala so that I would be able to use it for calculating time differences between 2 such values in minutes?

It gets tricky since the timestamp value in string does not have separator like - or /

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `unix_timestamp` and provide a suitable date format:

```
select unix_timestamp(column, 'yyyyMMddHHmmss') from mytable;
```

See the [docs](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html#datetime_functions__unix_timestamp) for more information.